# ARM assembly Reverse Polish evaluator

Tags: assembly, arm, reverse, postfix-notation

I have a Reverse Polish evaluator to write in ARM assembly code.
So far I have written the addition but I am stuck.
I have to get my arguments from the commandline so for example
RPeval 1 2 + = 
must return 3 in r1

i know that the error comes from line 40, where I am verifying that the argument is a number.
WHen i compare the contents of the address it is too big of a value and I am confused on why is that...

Atoi is a procedure called from another program, returns in r0 the integer of an ascii string which address is r0. Do you know of any way to do this?

I tried doing ldrb instead of ldr but it is still not working, i get the value 242 for '1'.

here is my code:

```
    .text
    .global _start
    .equ EXIT, 1
    .equ WRITE, 4
    .equ STDOUT, 1
    .equ STDERR, 2

_start:
    ldr r0, [sp]    @argc value
    add r1, sp, #8
    bl main
    mov r0, #0  
    mov r7, #EXIT
    svc 0

main: 
    push {lr}
    mov r0, r1
    bl rpEval
    pop {pc}

####################################################################
# rpEval - evaluate a Reverse Polish expression
# parameters:
#   r0 - address of a null-terminated array of string addresses
# returns:
#   r0 - zero means success, nonzero means failure:
#        failure values:
#          1: Missing end-of-expression marker
#          2: Too few operands
#          3: Too many operands
#          4: Illegal expression item
#   r1 - the value of the expression, if r0 is zero

rpEval:
    push {r4, r5,lr}
    mov fp, sp      @save sp
    mov r4, r0      @save address of start of array

0:  ldr r0, [r4], #4
    cmp r0, #'0
    blo less
    cmp r0, #'9
    bhi grt
    bl atoi
    push {r0}
    b 0b

less:   cmp r0, #'+
    beq add
    b invalid

invalid: 
    mov r0, #4
    mov sp, fp
    pop {r4, r5, pc}

add:    pop {r2, r3}
    mov r1, #0
    add r1, r2, r3
    push {r1}
    b 0b

grt:    cmp r:0, #'=
    bne invalid
    pop {r1}
    pop {r2}
    cmp r2, fp
    beq tmo
    mov sp, fp
    pop {r4, r5, pc}

tmo: 
    mov r0, #2
    mov sp, fp
    pop {r4, r5, pc}
```

Comment: 0:  ldr r0, [r4], #4                         This line is where the problem lies

Comment: `int main(int argc, char **argv)`. Not `char *argv` ;)